# Invoke constructor with unknown parameters

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

I've got set of classes: `TestClass1`, `TestClass2` and `TestClass3`. All those classes inherits from class `MainTestClass`. Classes `TestClass1`, `TestClass2` and `TestClass3` has different constructors. For example:

```
TestClass1(String s)
TestClass2(Integer i)
TestClass3(Double d)
```

Classes can have more than one constructor - each different from others.

Now I want to randomly create instances of these classes and store them in List. To do that, I store `Class` objects of `TestClass1`, ... using `TestClass1.class`, ... in a List. Then, I get for example first constructor of each class, that has non-zero parameters count. Now, when I want to create object using `newInstance()` method, I don't know types and count of arguments to pass to this specific constructor.

Is it possible to achieve something like this using reflection? I have been thinking about something like

```
setConstructorArgument(int number, Object value)
```

or

```
setConstructorArguments(Object[] arguments)
```

Do similar methods exists in Java?

Comment: the [Constructor object has a newInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object...)) method that takes arguments. You can also interrgate the constructor to get the argument types and quantity.

Comment: Okay, my fault. I didn't know, you can substitute `Object... initargs` with `Object[] initargs`. You can post your comment as answer and I'll accept it as correct one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Constructor Object has a newInstance method that can take arguments to construct
the class it belongs to. Obviously the arguments have to match the parameters expected
the getParameterTypes method can provide those.

Object... initargs does in fact mean Object[] initargs, except it allows the syntax

```
newInstance(param1, param2, param3);
```

as well as

```
newInstance(new Object[]{param1, param2, param3});
```

You should also bear in mind that

```
newInstance(null);
```

does not mean

```
newInstance(new Object[]{null});
```

which catches out people from time to time.

personally I do not like varargs, but c'est la vie.